# Failed to run multiple Rails apps with Unicorn + Nginx on single AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I know this issue has been discussed several times but I had no luck and I couldn't fix the issue.

I am going to **run multiple Rails apps** on **AWS EC2 Instance** with **Unicorn** and **Nginx**.

I could run one rails app on **mydomain.com**

So the project will be on **mydomain.com/app1** and **mydomain.com/app2**

Projects are in **/home/ubuntu/work/app1** and **/home/ubuntu/work/app2**

***/etc/nginx/sites-available/default***

```
upstream app1 {
 server unix:/home/ubuntu/work/app1/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
upstream app2 {
 server unix:/home/ubuntu/work/app2/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name localhost;
 root /home/ubuntu/work;
 access_log /home/ubuntu/work/log/nginx.access.log;
 error_log /home/ubuntu/work/log/nginx.error.log;

location /app1/ {
 root /home/ubuntu/work/app1/public;
 rewrite ^/app1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
 try_files /app1/$uri/index.html /app1/$uri.html /app1/$uri @app1;
}
location /app2/ {
 root /home/ubuntu/work/app2/public;
 rewrite ^/app2/(.*)$ /$1 break;
 try_files /app2/$uri/index.html /app2/$uri.html /app2/$uri @app2;
}

location @app1 {
 proxy_pass http://app1;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_redirect off;
}
location @app2 {
 proxy_pass http://app2;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_redirect off;
}

 error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
 client_max_body_size 4G;
 keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

The error I am getting now. (Looks like the internal errors)

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

I have checked these files to check logs.

```
/home/ubuntu/work/log/nginx.error.log
/home/ubuntu/work/fastland1/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log 
/home/ubuntu/work/fastland2/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log
```

But I can't find any log in `nginx.error.log`

And there were just warning in 2 `unicorn.stderr.log` files. 
There were not any errors.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What errors you see or problems you experience?

Comment: Hi @MLu, I just added the error details.

Comment: Is there any permission to set to run successfully?

Comment: I don’t know Unicorn sorry. Just wanted to point out that you need to describe the actual errors for others to be able to help.